# PermGenSpace error in Tomcat with geonetwork 3.0

Tags: java, tomcat, geonetwork, memory, jvm

I'm running a geonetwork 3.0.1 instance on tomcat7. Regularly, i.e. every few actions of my only user, my tomcat runs into a `PermGenSpace` error. This especially occurs during harvesting of other catalogues.

I already configured geonetwork to use Postgres (postgres.xml). Then I adapted `/ect/default/tomcat7` and set in the `JAVA_OPTS`: `-Xms=1024m -XmX=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m`. If I get it right, that should be the maximum tolerable values, as my server runs on 4GB RAM. Actually I am not sure, if those values are actually applied by the JVM, as I could not prove it with memory monitoring.

As the latest configuration improvement, I set the geonetwork_data_dir outside the tomcat webapp path. Since then, it seems to behave a bit improved, but I am still affected by this tiring `PermGenSpace` error.

Are there best practice experiences, which values to use, especially for `-XX:MaxPermSize`?

Are there suggestions, what else to enhance in the configuration?

**EDIT:**

I changed my server configuration and run with 6GB now. Other reconfiguration has been changing the JAVA_OPTS to

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xrs -XX:PerfDataSamplingInterval=500 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

The out of memory errors disappeared until now, after a few tests. Also harvesting a remote CSW ran quickly and without disruption.

So in general I can run geonetwork with the 1GB heap and 256 Perm space as proposed in the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao,
 -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m is way too much IMHO.

I mean, if you have 4GB of RAM available you already have the OS, PostgreSQL then the Tomcat process for Tomcat with a max heap of 2GB. If account also for native memory use by the java process for Tomcat and then you put also 2GB for PermGen then you might soon be swapping!

I believe 1GB heap is more than enough for GN and 128M or 256M should be fine as well for PermGen.

Hope this helps, 
Simone.

Comment: Thanks for that opinion. I can't really imagine not to suffer from PermGen error with 256M if I have troubles with the current config. But I will test this. Do you think, allowing less memory may increase internal optimization for garbage collection and therefore probably result in better performance?

Comment: You observations are sound indeed. We have some work upcoming with GN3, I will ping the devs as they start to do some testing and see if this is an issue in the code or a misconfiguration.

I would suggest to ping again if you don't hear anything in 1w or so.

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: I tried to configure geonetwork with the values you provided. My complete line of JAVA_OPTS in /etc/default/tomcat7 is

`JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xrs -XX:PerfDataSamplingInterval=500 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"`
But still suffering from PermGen or OutOfMemory error now (which occurs later now, btw). Could you find any hints according to this?

Comment: Changed server RAM to 6GB, running with the following JAVA_OPTS: `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xrs -XX:PerfDataSamplingInterval=500 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"` works fine after a short test.

Comment: Ciao tareq,
the doc at this link could help a bit. I would also be interested in your feedback over it.

Comment: Could you include the mentioned link please?;)

Comment: Ops http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/bev/doc/

Comment: My setup was bit different, maybe because I run on Ubuntu. Interesting for me though the system requirements. I just recognize, I wasn't able to run at 4GB even for dev, but that may be reasoned by my setup as well. Btw, Oracle doesn't seem to allow access to 1.7 JRE/ JDK anymore.

Comment: it should, it is just that you have to fiddle a bit to get to it.